# How can i make something Invisible if the Light is on?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation

So i make a "Lights Out" animation and there is a light that is flickering and I want to make a Person Invisible when the Light is On and Visible when the light is of. How can I do that ?

Comment: you can create shapekeys on the visibility (camera) icon of the Outliner that you activate/deactivate

Comment: I believe the word keyframes was intended ... not shapekeys ...in the comment by @moonboots

Comment: I dont get how it works. I click on the Camera Icon and turn it off but it just turns on again.

Comment: First click the camera icon in the outliner to be active or inactive then you insert a keyframe .You insert a keyframe by pressing the letter I while the mouse is over the camera icon.

Comment: Please specify the renderer you are using in your original question above for clarity. Cycles Render or Blender Render.  There are always a few ways to do similar things in Blender.

Comment: @ atomicbezierslinger: yes, sorry, I meant "keyframes", you can create keyframes on the visibility (camera) icon of the Outliner that you activate/deactivate   ;)

Comment: Its about an Object. I want to make an Object invisible. I click on the Camera icon instert the Keyframe and nothing happens. The Object is always Visible.

Comment: See my answer edit below.

Comment: Drivers would be the go IMO. The hide / render properties can be driven via the property you have animated to make light flicker. What property of the light have you animated with keyframes?

Answer (score 2):

First click the camera icon in the outliner to be active or inactive then you insert a keyframe .You insert a keyframe by pressing the letter <kbd>I</kbd> while the mouse is over the camera icon.  Or context click to see the menu appear with a choice insert keyframe.

I suggest inserting at least 3 keyframes and traveling through the frames to see how the setting is maintained until the next keyframe.  Look at the camera icon and see if it become bright and then less bright or muted while moving the frame position.

[image]

The render visibility camera icon and the 3D View visibility eye icon near the arrow. Yellow indicates a keyframe. Image above.

Please know that for options and convenience the camera render icon does [**not**] affect the 3D View.  You must press render to see the difference.  You can animate 3D View visibility of the [Person] with the 3D View eye icon in the outliner near the camera icon... and that is your choice. It may be useful to know where the [Person] is, even if [ Person] is not rendered on some frame. Blender can suit your needs. You may also keyframe the 3D View drawing of  the [Person] as wire or bounds. The hint of the [Person] may be valuable.

- You might even consider changing layer visibility to avoid clutter.
- If you have a simple still shot ... you can move objects off the viewable area. This idea is for simple circumstances only.

Comment: I am in Cycels Render. But it dosnt Work. I click on the Icon and i instert the Keyframe but it stays on.

Comment: Please remove/delete the comment.  It is not in the best place.

Comment: @Mr.Science Please remove your comment above.